# Create 2D numpy array from buffer

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, buffer

Consider a system with `n_channels` transmitting `n_samples` at a given sampling rate. The 1D buffer containing the timestamps and the 2D buffer containing `(n_channels, n_samples)` is:

```
from ctypes import c_double, c_float

# Assume a 2-second window, 3 channels, sampled at 1024 Hz
# data: (n_channels, n_samples) = (3, 2048)
# timestamps: (n_samples,) = (2048,)
n_channels = 3
n_samples = 2048
n_data_values = n_channels * n_samples
data_buffer = (c_float * n_data_values)()
ts_buffer = (c_double * n_samples)()
```

I have a C++ binary library that fills the buffer. The function can be summarized as:

```
from ctypes import byref

fill_buffers(
    byref(data_buffer),
    byref(ts_buffer),
)
```

At this point, I have 2 filled buffers, one with 2048 elements (timestamps) and one with 3* 2048 elements (data). I want to load as efficiently as possible those 2 buffers in a numpy array.

`np.frombuffer` seems amazing to read 1D array, e.g. the `timestamps`, but I can't find a counterpart for N-dim arrays.

```
# read from buffer for the 1D array
timestamps = np.frombuffer(ts_buffer)  # 192 ns ± 1.11 ns per loop
timestamps = np.array(ts_buffer)  # 854 ns ± 2.99 ns per loop
```

For now, the data array is loaded with:

```
data = np.array(data_buffer).reshape(-1, n_channels, order="C").T
```

Any way to use the same efficient method as `np.frombuffer` while providing the output shape and the order?

---

This question is different from [How can I initialize a NumPy array from a multidimensional buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46692086/how-can-i-initialize-a-numpy-array-from-a-multidimensional-buffer) and from [How to restore a 2-dimensional numpy.array from a bytestring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165367/how-to-restore-a-2-dimensional-numpy-array-from-a-bytestring) since it does not focus on an alternative to `np.frombuffer`, but an alternative as efficient.

---

**EDIT**: Why is `np.frombuffer(data_buffer).reshape(-1, n_channels).T` not working? With 3 channels and 1024 points (to speed-up my testing), I get `len(data_buffer) = 3072`, but:

```
np.array(data_buffer).reshape(-1, 3).T.size = 3072
np.frombuffer(data_buffer).reshape(-1, 3).T.size = 1536
```

The application is a LabStreamingLayer buffer. The buffer is filled here https://github.com/labstreaminglayer/liblsl-Python/blob/87276974a311bcf7ceb3383e9d04c6bdcf302771/pylsl/pylsl.py#L854-L861
using the C++ library https://github.com/sccn/liblsl with specifically this function https://github.com/sccn/liblsl/blob/08aa186326e9a339316b7d5677ef31b3651b4aad/src/lsl_inlet_c.cpp#L180-L185

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `np.frombuffer(data_buffer, dtype=c_float).reshape(-1, n_channels, order="C").T` not work correctly? As you are doing it `np.array` treats the buffer as a 1D array until you reshape it anyways.

For me the following code produces the right shapes. (Hard to verify if it works correctly without a MWE for the data that should be in the buffers).

```
import numpy as np
from ctypes import c_double, c_float

# Assume a 2-second window, 3 channels, sampled at 1024 Hz
# data: (n_channels, n_samples) = (3, 2048)
# timestamps: (n_samples,) = (2048,)
n_channels = 3
n_samples = 2048
n_data_values = n_channels * n_samples
data_buffer = (c_float * n_data_values)() # Note that c_float is typically 32 bytes while c_double and numpy's default is 64 bytes
ts_buffer = (c_double * n_samples)()

# Create a mock buffer

input_data = np.arange(0,n_data_values, dtype=c_float)
input_data_buffer = input_data.tobytes()


timestamps = np.frombuffer(ts_buffer) 

# Note to specify the data type for the array of floats
data = np.frombuffer(input_data_buffer, dtype=c_float).reshape(-1, n_channels, order="C").T
# data has values 0,1,2 for first time point, 3,4,5 for second, and so on
```

Comment: I'll try this one (just in case), but when I did `np.frombuffer(data_buffer)`, I got only 2048 elements (a single channel).

Comment: Hard to say without the code creating the buffers, but for the code I posted I get a 3,2048 data array. Perhaps the c code is not creating/filling the buffer correctly

Comment: So there is something weird into play, I was also expecting your solution to work. But I'm getting only half of the data, even thou the buffer len is correct. C++ is above my current knowledge, I edited my post with additional information and links, but it seems like some digging into this library is required to figure out what is happening here..

Comment: Have you tried specifying the dtype for from buffer? Perhaps np.array does it automatically, but I needed to specify dtype as c_float not c_double, e.g. numpy's default data type. c_float is half the size of c_double so you'll get twice as many values. (c_float and c_double may be architecture/compiler dependent, but I'm not very aware of working with c/c++ bindings in Python.)

Comment: And I'm an idiot.. obviously, I need to load with the correct `dtype`.. Thanks a lot for the help, works like a charm!!